# How to set a localStorage object as a variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wanted to make an app with JavaScript using the localStorage object so I can store information so next time I open the file the info stored from before is still there. I was aiming for some kind of clock of how long you have been on the site for. How could use `localStorage.setItem("example", "variable")` so I could use it as a counter for the clock? Here's one of my test code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Tracking Time</title>
<style>
#time {
    font-size: 250%
}
</style>
<center>
<body>
<h1><font face="fantasy">The Time You Have Had This Tab Open</font></h1>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<h1 id="time"><font face="impact" size="10">00:00:00:00:00:00</font></h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>

// Update Count

setInterval(function () {
 localStorage.setItem("sec", 0);

}, 1000)

//


// Update Text

setInterval(function (){
$("#time").text( + " year(s) " +  + " month(s) " +  + " day(s) " +  + " hour(s) " +  + " minute(s) " + localStorage.getItem("sec") + " second(s)")
}, 1)
</script>

</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Sorry that it is not complete but I need help for this. Any way I could use it as a variable? Please provide an example. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a variable...

Comment: You should read up on the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Specifically, you can use `Date.now()` to get the current time then you can use that as a reference point for how long they've been on there.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to use this as an example. Sorry if I didn't come up with another better example but if I use a variable, then it would reset the next time I open the file right?

Comment: @Cool123, Not really... Most useful _IF_ condition should be used to check the value present in the `localStorage` and proceed accordingly...

Comment: All I'm asking is if there is a way to do this

Comment: @Rayon How is any of that helpful? @Cool123 Yes it would be reset every time you open the page if you just assigned it to a variable. What you might do instead is add a "time" item to `localStorage` if one doesn't exist. Then in your interval, add 1000 to that "time" item. That will tell you how many milliseconds they've been on the site. You can use that for other time conversions.

Comment: @MikeC, Do highlight what is not useful...

Comment: @Mike C Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Rayon They're asking how to store data locally and use that to determine the total amount of time that the user has spent on their site. Telling them to just "use a variable" won't help especially since they're asking about "Any way I could use it as a variable?". Then just telling them to use an `if` statement isn't helpful at all. Programs use `if` statements all the time! What matters is why/where/how to use that if logic.

Comment: Can someone please just provide an example of a counter updating every second they are on the file and pausing if they have closed the file and resuming once it is open again.

Comment: @MikeC, Answer for _"Any way I could use it as a variable?"_ was _"You can use a variable.."_ and when OP thought about value getting `reset` after refresh, I did suggest him about using a condition to test whether he has got any value in `Storage`.. I personally feel this question lacks research and proving everything freely will not help the cause... _"why/where/how to use that if logic"_ is what OP needs to think...

Comment: @Rayon but still, once you open the file again, the variable that is set in the code will reset it to 0 again.

Comment: @Cool123 and the one who found your comment useful, Have a look... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/uu17guwf/

Comment: @Cool123 Thanks too Rayon! I see there are a lot of answers to this question. I didn't use the Number() function so that's why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to set some kind of "time" property in the local storage if one doesn't exist.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('time') === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('time', 0);
}
```

Then during a loop, you can increment the amount of time saved in the local storage.

```
var intervalTime = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  // localStorage saves as strings so lets make it an integer
  var totalTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('time'));
  localStorage.setItem('time', totalTime + intervalTime);
}, intervalTime);
```

This will save the total number of milliseconds the user has spent on your site. You can then use those milliseconds to show how long they've been on the site.

```
var totalMilliseconds = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('time'));
var totalTime = new Date(totalMilliseconds);
var hours = totalTime.getHours();
var minutes = totalTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = totalTime.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Oh, ok... you set an if statement. Thanks Mike!